# Query in Oracle is not respecting the AND and WHERE conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this Query in Oracle:

```
SELECT serverHostName,
      operatingSystem,
      serverClass
FROM Server_Inventory A
WHERE A.serverHostName NOT IN 
    (SELECT rltd_ServerHostname
     FROM App_Server_Relationship)
AND A.serverHostName NOT IN 
    (SELECT rltd_ServerHostname
     FROM DataBase_Server_Relationship)
AND A.operatingSystem NOT IN ('OS1','OS3','OS5')
AND A.serverClass NOT IN ('CLASS_3','CLASS_6');
```

What I'm trying to get is the list of servers from my Server_Inventory table that do not have an Application and a Data Base linked or related to it. I do get some results, but after some manual validation, I noticed that some servers were being excluded even though they do not fall under the excluding conditions.
 For example, let's say I have a server called "Server_24GW1". If I execute the query like this:

```
SELECT serverHostName,
      operatingSystem,
      serverClass
FROM Server_Inventory A
WHERE A.serverHostName NOT IN 
    (SELECT rltd_ServerHostname
     FROM App_Server_Relationship)
AND A.serverHostName NOT IN 
    (SELECT rltd_ServerHostname
     FROM DataBase_Server_Relationship)
```

I get the following result when I look for the Server_24GW1 server:

```
serverHostName   |  operatingSystem   | serverClass
----------------------------------------------------
Server_24GW1     |   (null)           |  CLASS_10
```

But if I execute the query WITH the conditions, meaning these:

```
AND A.operatingSystem NOT IN ('OS1','OS3','OS5')
AND A.serverClass NOT IN ('CLASS_3','CLASS_6');
```

I get Nothing when I try to look for Server_24GW1, even though the `operatingSystem` and `serverClass` do not fall under the excluding conditions.

Does somebody know what could I be possibly doing wrong?

Comment: NULLs are weird. NULLs are never NOT IN anything. Nor is it ever IN anything. Every nullable field needs to be wrapped in something that makes it not null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NULLs work differently to everything else

Try this. Although it will probably stop use of an index on `operatingSystem`, the logic will work out the way you want.

```
AND NVL(A.operatingSystem,' ') NOT IN ('OS1','OS3','OS5')
```

Or this

```
AND (A.operatingSystem NOT IN ('OS1','OS3','OS5') OR A.operatingSystem IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

`A.operatingSystem NOT IN ('OS1','OS3','OS5')` is a syntax shortcut equivalent to:

```
NOT (A.operatingSystem = 'OS1' OR A.operatingSystem ='OS3' OR A.operatingSystem ='OS5')
```

If A.operatingSystem IS NULL then you are attempting to **compare NULL using equals** and that **always fails**.

To overcome this specifically cater for the possibility of NULL for the comparisons, e.g.

```
AND (A.operatingSystem NOT IN ('OS1','OS3','OS5') OR A.operatingSystem IS NULL)
```

NB: It is possible to use NVL() or COALESCE() as an alternative, but, if using that approach the condition won't be able to make use of an index  and this can adversely affect query performance (*unless a matching function based index exists*).